# Does $templateCache only work on URL, or can you use it to fetch a HTML file?

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to get this command to work...

```
var template = $templateCache.get('nameOfTemplate.html');
```

But no matter what I do I get an undefined result back.

```
    var test = $templateCache.get('./templateBase.html')
    console.log("TEMPLATE: " + test)
    var test = $templateCache.get('/templateBase.html')
    console.log("TEMPLATE: " + test)
    var test = $templateCache.get('templateBase.html')
    console.log("TEMPLATE: " + test)
    var test = $templateCache.get('index.html')
    console.log("TEMPLATE: " + test)
    var test = $templateCache.get('app.js')
    console.log("TEMPLATE: " + test)
```

But all I get is...

```
TEMPLATE: undefined
TEMPLATE: undefined
TEMPLATE: undefined
TEMPLATE: undefined
TEMPLATE: undefined
```

Is that because this only works on URL's?

My `templateBase.html` is in the same folder as my controller.

All I want is to read the content and put into a variable.

I just tried

```
test = require('./templateBase.html');
console.log("require: " + test)
```

which worked, but `require` reads the template when the whole app is loaded, and since I got a lot of templates this is not a very good solution.

Comment: [`$templateCache`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$templateCache) works like in-memory key-value storage for the string templates (it will not fetch it from your server). You will always get `undefined` if the template was not previously loaded into it. You can use `$http.get` to load your template from server (on `app.run` for example) and `$templateCache.put` to load it into `$templateCache` storage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are able to load already cached items by using `$templateCache.get()`. I promise your templates are not cached at the time you try to load them -> this results in `undefined`. You said: `All I want is to read the content and put into a variable.`. You could use `$http`to load your files like in this **[demo fiddle](https://plnkr.co/edit/RXEB8mmVimZGuSPd61VA?p=preview)**:

```
$http.get('./template.en.html').then(function (result) {           
  var data = result.data;
  console.log(data);
});
```

---

#### Different approach with caching

This example will also store your template inside the `$templateCache` for later use.

```
$http.get('./template.en.html').then(function (result) { 

  //put template into cache
  $templateCache.put('myTemplateName', result.data);

  //fetch result and log it
  var data = result.data;
  console.log(data);

});
```

More details about templates caching on [$templateCache documentation website](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$templateCache).

Comment: Thanks Lin - I think its just me who do not understand the use correctly :-)

Comment: it didnt quite work...  `GET http://localhost:8080/templateBase.html 404 (Not Found)` the thing is that all the templates are stored in the controllers folders, so I cant get to them via an URL.  Would it be possible to some how just read them from disk?

Comment: @torbenrudgaard No. You need an public URL to access them. Store your templates on a folder on your webserver.

Comment: Ok I guess there is no harm in doing that :)  Thanks